# Eureka with Node-Js client registration succeed but heartbeat failed(always re-register)

Tags: node.js, netflix-eureka

I have an eureka server with multiple clients, one of them is nodejs ,
all the java clients work as expected but the nodejs gives the following errors:

```
retrieved full registry successfully
registered with eureka:  dbServer/dbServer
eureka heartbeat FAILED, Re-registering app
retrieved full registry successfully
registered with eureka:  dbServer/dbServer
eureka heartbeat FAILED, Re-registering app
...
```

In the eureka server on the other hand I can see the following:

```
DS: Registry: lease doesn't exist, , registering resource: DBSERVER - dbServer 
Not Found (Renew): DBSERVER - dbServer
Registered instance DBSERVER/DBSERVER with status UP (replication=false)
Registered instance DBSERVER/DBSERVER with status UP (replication=true)
DS: Registry: lease doesn't exist, registering resource: DBSERVER - dbServer
Not Found (Renew): DBSERVER - dbServer
...
```

The client configuration(Node js):

```
const client = new Eureka({
// application instance information
instance: {
    app: 'dbServer',
    instanceId: 'dbServer',
    hostName: 'localhost',
    ipAddr: '127.0.0.1',
    port: {
        '$': port,
        '@enabled': 'true',
    },
    vipAddress: 'dbServer',
    dataCenterInfo: {
        '@class': 'com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo',
        name: 'MyOwn',
    },
    registerWithEureka: true,
    fetchRegistry: true
},
eureka: {
    // eureka server host / port
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8761,
    servicePath: '/eureka/apps',
},
 });

   client.logger.level('debug');
   client.start((error) => {
           console.log(error || 'complete');
    });
```

Does anyone has a solution to this issue? it the commands still manage to arrive to the client but the logs are filled , 
Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer is simple,

```
     instance: {
          app: 'dbServer',
          instanceId: 'dbServer',
```

InstanceId and app name cannot be identical.

Changing any one will solve this issue.

Comment: for my case i had attempted to edit this section , please dont modify anything here 

   `dataCenterInfo: {
            '@class': 'com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo',
            name: 'MyOwn',
        },`